# CSS transition hover on parent effect on child

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to animate inside button but for some reason it won't work. Width of the button should shrink to 0 to the left

HTML

```
<div class="siteBtnShare">
    <div class="share-text-wrapper">
        <span class="share-text">SHARE</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.siteBtnShare  {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Novecentosanswide-Medium';
width: 40px;
transition: width 1s;
overflow:hidden;

.share-text-wrapper{
    width: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}

&:hover .share-text-wrapper{
    width: 0;
}

}
```

EDIT: - Inside the button should shrink to 0, but it doesn't do anything. It remains visible

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: How do you want to animate it by hover, click?

Comment: on hover. And I it doesn't work in a way that it doesn't do anything. The inside text is still visible

Answer (score 0):

The width does shrink, you just don't see it because the text flows outside of the container:

```css
.siteBtnShare  {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Novecentosanswide-Medium';
width: 40px;
transition: width 1s;
overflow:hidden;
}

.share-text-wrapper{
    width: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.siteBtnShare:hover .share-text-wrapper{
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="siteBtnShare">
    <div class="share-text-wrapper">
        <span class="share-text">SHARE</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working code in SCSS:

```
.siteBtnShare  {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Novecentosanswide-Medium';
width: 40px;
transition: width 1s;
overflow:hidden;

.share-text-wrapper{
    width: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

&:hover .share-text-wrapper{
    width: 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this, without the FontAwesome icon or with, as per your preference.

**SCSS**

```
.siteBtnShare {
    background: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    width: auto;
  color: #333;
    &:hover {
        .share-text-wrapper {
            .share-text {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
}
.label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
  color: #888;
}
.share-text-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: -1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    .share-text {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 0%;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="siteBtnShare">
    <span class="label"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <div class="share-text-wrapper">
        <div class="share-text">
            Share It Out
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Jabideau/3bo4zxgc/